# Increment value upto certain value in the same column

Tags: sql-server

Below is the table that I have:

```
companyId   country  Year
18507       Denmark  2002
18507       Denmark  2008
```

I would like to update the year column with all the years from min year to max year as shown below:

```
companyId   country  Year
18507       Denmark  2002
18507       Denmark  2003
18507       Denmark  2004
18507       Denmark  2005
18507       Denmark  2006
18507       Denmark  2007
18507       Denmark  2008
```

These min and max values are differenct for each of the company that I have.
Experts Please help me to get this done.

Thanks
Satish Kumar Peddi

Comment: Do you have any other companies or coutries in table?

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work using CTE, not sure how that would perform on bigger amount of data.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    [companyID] INT
    , [Country] VARCHAR(100)
    , [Year] INT
);


INSERT INTO #Test
    ([companyID], [Country], [Year])
VALUES
    (18507, 'Denmark', 2002)
    , (18507, 'Denmark', 2008)
```

Actual Query

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT T.[companyID]
        , T.[Country]
        , MIN(T.[Year]) AS CurYear
        , MIN(T.[Year]) AS MinYear
        , MAX(T.[Year]) AS MaxYear
    FROM #Test AS T
    GROUP BY T.[companyID], T.[Country]

    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.[companyID]
        , T.[Country]
        , C.CurYear + 1
        , C.MinYear
        , C.MaxYear
    FROM #Test AS T
    INNER JOIN CTE AS C
        ON C.companyID = T.companyID
        AND C.Country = T.Country
    WHERE C.CurYear < C.MaxYear
)
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      companyID INT ,
      country NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      year INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 18507, 'Denmark', 2002 ),
        ( 18507, 'Denmark', 2008 ),
        ( 18507, 'Brasil', 2003 ),
        ( 18507, 'Brasil', 2005 ),
        ( 18508, 'Denmark', 2004 ),
        ( 18508, 'Denmark', 2007 );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   MIN(year) year ,
                        MAX(year) AS m
               FROM     @t
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   cte.year + 1 ,
                        m
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    cte.year < cte.m
             )
    SELECT  t.companyID ,
            t.country ,
            cte.year
    FROM    cte
            JOIN ( SELECT   companyID ,
                            country ,
                            MIN(year) AS mi ,
                            MAX(year) AS ma
                   FROM     @t
                   GROUP BY companyID ,
                            country
                 ) t ON cte.year BETWEEN t.mi AND t.ma
    ORDER BY t.companyID ,
            t.country ,
            cte.year
```

Output:

```
companyID   country year
18507       Brasil  2003
18507       Brasil  2004
18507       Brasil  2005
18507       Denmark 2002
18507       Denmark 2003
18507       Denmark 2004
18507       Denmark 2005
18507       Denmark 2006
18507       Denmark 2007
18507       Denmark 2008
18508       Denmark 2004
18508       Denmark 2005
18508       Denmark 2006
18508       Denmark 2007
```

Answer (score 0):

> use two variable for strat & end year and the lead command-

```
   DECLARE @startyear int
DECLARE @endyear int
SELECT @startyear= [Year]
,      @endyear=lead([Year],1) over ( order by Year)
FROM [dbo].[Testx]
ORDER BY [Year] desc

WHILE @startyear <= @endyear-2
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO testx ( companyId, country,   year         )
    VALUES            ( 18507,     'Denmark', @startyear+1 )
    SET @startyear=@startyear+1
END
SELECT companyID
,      Country
,      Year
FROM [dbo].[Testx]
ORDER BY YEAR
```

[image]